# Type safe, easy to understand matrix multiplication

Tags: haskell, matrix

I always hated matrices *(as they are taught in those linear algebra course books that I have browsed)*, because it's an obscure way of saying "a tuple of linear functions of same arity". It is very hard to remember which matrices you can multiply, what side the input is, what side the output, what transpositions should be done. Now, *(square)* matrices are a major example of a group, and matrices as an encoding of linear transformations are indispensable in differential geometry of any kind − for just two examples; so I had to stand up to it and design the matrices I would be able to like.

Now, one straightforward way of representing matrices in Haskell would be a nested list. Unfortunately, dealing in nested lists has proven to multiply my hate, rather than my matrices. I had to come up with a safer approach. What will follow is a take on it.

I post this code because it is actually above my head: I don't understand dependent typing at all, and half the language extensions I had to use I switched on because GHC told me to, not because I understand why they are indispensable here. I'd like to know if I'm on the right track − whether this code is sensible or not. I am happy about it now; I'd like to become less happy.

**Is this implementation actually as type safe as I think?**

#### Data.Nat

```
module Data.Nat where

data Nat = Z | S Nat
```

#### Data.Vector

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    DataKinds
  , KindSignatures
  , FlexibleInstances
  , ScopedTypeVariables
  , MultiParamTypeClasses
  , FunctionalDependencies
  , UndecidableInstances
  #-}

module Data.Vector where

import Data.Nat

newtype Vector (n :: Nat) a = Vector { unVector :: [a] } deriving Show

-- `vector` is thanks to HTNV @ stackoverflow.com/a/49120144/2108477
class MkVector n a n' r | r -> n a n' where
  mkVector :: (Vector n a -> Vector n' a) -> r

instance MkVector Z a n (Vector n a) where
  mkVector f = f $ Vector []

instance (MkVector n a n' r) => MkVector (S n) a n' (a -> r) where
  mkVector f x = mkVector $ \(Vector xs) -> f $ Vector $ x:xs

vector :: MkVector n a n r => r
vector = mkVector id

v0 :: Vector Z a
v0 = Vector [ ]

put :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (S n) a
put x (Vector xs) = Vector (x:xs)

instance Functor (Vector n) where
    fmap f (Vector xs) = Vector (fmap f xs)

instance Foldable (Vector n) where
    foldMap f (Vector xs) = foldMap f xs

instance Repeat (Vector n) => Applicative (Vector n) where
    pure x = rep x
    (Vector fs) <*> (Vector xs) = Vector (zipWith ($) fs xs)

class Repeat a where
    rep :: forall x. x -> a x

instance Repeat (Vector Z) where
    rep _ = v0

instance Repeat (Vector n) => Repeat (Vector (S n)) where
    rep (x :: x) = Vector $ x: unVector (rep x :: Vector n x)
```

#### Data.Matrix

```
{-# LANGUAGE
    DataKinds
  , KindSignatures
  , FlexibleInstances
  , FlexibleContexts
  , UndecidableInstances
  , ExistentialQuantification
  , StandaloneDeriving
  , DeriveFunctor
  #-}

module Data.Matrix where

import Data.Nat
import Data.Vector
import Data.List (foldl1')

-- | A linear function of n variables.
newtype LinearFunction (n :: Nat) a = LinearFunction (Vector n a)
    deriving (Show, Functor)

instance Repeat (Vector n) => Applicative (LinearFunction n) where
    pure x = LinearFunction $ pure x
    (LinearFunction fs) <*> (LinearFunction xs) = LinearFunction $ fs <*> xs

-- | A few functions of the same arity.
data Matrix inp outp a = Matrix (Vector outp (LinearFunction inp a))
                       | forall inter. Sequence (Matrix inp inter a) (Matrix inter outp a)

deriving instance Show a => Show (Matrix inp outp a)

v1 = vector 1 2
v2 = vector 3 5
m1 :: Matrix (S (S Z)) (S (S Z)) Integer
m1 = Matrix (vector (LinearFunction v1) (LinearFunction v2))

-- |
--
-- λ apply v1 (Sequence m1 (Sequence m1 m1))
-- Vector [191,493]
--
apply :: Num a => Vector inp a -> Matrix inp outp a -> Vector outp a
apply v (Matrix (Vector fs)) = Vector $ applyFunction v <$> fs
apply v (Sequence m1 m2) = v `apply` m1 `apply` m2

-- |
--
-- λ applyFunction v1 (LinearFunction v2)
-- 13
--
applyFunction :: Num a => Vector n a -> LinearFunction n a -> a
applyFunction (Vector xs) (LinearFunction (Vector qs)) = sum $ zipWith (*) xs qs

compose_trivial, compose
    :: (Num a, Repeat (Vector inter), Repeat (Vector inp))
    => Matrix inp inter a -> Matrix inter outp a -> Matrix inp outp a

compose_trivial = Sequence

-- |
--
-- λ v1 `apply` (m1 `compose` m1 `compose` m1)
-- Vector {unVector = [191,493]}
--
compose (Matrix fs) (Matrix gs) = Matrix $ fmap (createRow fs) gs
  where
    createRow fs (LinearFunction qs)
        = let (Vector xs) = (\q -> fmap (* q)) <$> qs <*> fs
          in  foldl1' (\xs ys -> (+) <$> xs <*> ys) xs
compose m1 m2@Sequence{} = Sequence m1 m2
compose m1@Sequence{} m2 = Sequence m1 m2
```

Comment: Why no one wants to review this. =(

Comment: More code = more to read = more to review = needs more time. Also, you're using features that are seldom reviewed. There are 7 questions that use `DataKinds`, and only 3 of them have been reviewed yet, so it might take some time. That being said, what was your rational to use a `newtype` instead of a GADT for `Vector`?

Comment: @Zeta I do not understand the hype about generalized algebraic types, I do not see the benefits they supposedly bring, I did not want to blindly copycat advanced code. In other words, there is simply no rationale. // Looks like there's only a handful of people doing reviews of Haskell code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Module names

Your module names clash with modules in popular packages. `Data.Vector` is provided by `vector`, `Data.Matrix` by `matrix`, `Data.Nat` by `data-nat`, although the last isn't often used. If you ever want to use `Data.Vector` in your project (for constant indexing, for example) you will have to pull some tricks.

Instead either use some other names, or use `Ignat` or `Insarov` in your module path as long as you're not sure what final name you want to use, e.g.

```
module Ignat.Data.Vector
```

or

```
module Data.Ignat.Vector
```

or

```
module Data.Vector.Ignat
```

## Type signatures

There are several top-level type bindings that are missing a signature.

## Type safety

> Is this implementation actually as type safe as I think?

It's possible to create `Vector`'s with wrong sizes:

```
main = print (Vector [] :: Vector (S Z) Int)
```

That's because the `n` parameter in your `newtype` is a phantom. Therefore, we can even use `coerce` from `Data.Coerce` to change vectors into arbitrary other ones:

```
main = print (coerce (v0 :: Vector Z Int) :: Vector (S (S Z)) Int)
```

Now you might say that this is an obvious malicous attempt to break type safety. However, we don't need `coerce` to do that. We can just write our own variant by accident, for example to use some list functions:

```
listFunc :: [Int] -> [Int] -- some library function you want to use

broken :: Vector n a -> Vector k a
broken = Vector . listFunc . unVector
```

We can use `listFunc = id` or `listFunc = take 2` to see that it's possible to convert between vectors arbitrarily. This means that we can, by a small unfortunate accident, create a function that will happily compile:

```
apply :: Num a => Vector inp a -> Matrix inp outp a -> Vector out a
```

Note the missing `p` in `Vector outp a`.

In order to make those modules type safe, you ***have to*** constrain the exports so that no `Vector` or `Matrix` can be build or matched with their constructors our of their respective module. You had a similar loophole in [your prime](/questions/176212/a-type-for-prime-numbers) code, by the way.

A `Vector` based on GADTs does not have this problem:

```
data Vector (n :: Nat) a where
  VNil  :: Vector Z a
  VCons :: a -> Vector n a -> Vector (S n) a
```

[Fixed-Length Vector Types in Haskell](https://blog.jle.im/entry/fixed-length-vector-types-in-haskell.html) by Justin Le is worth a read at that point.

## `compose`

`compose` has a worst- case \$\mathcal O(nkm)\$ complexity due to the matrix-matrix multiplication. If possible, you never actually want to use matrix-matrix multiplication, only matrix-vector ones, since the asymptotic time complexity is a lot better. If we have

$$
   A B x
$$
with \$A \in \mathbb K^{n\times k} \$, \$B \in \mathbb K^{k\times m} \$, \$x \in \mathbb K^{m} \$, we end up with

$$
   \mathcal O(apply(mult(AB),x)) = \mathcal O(nkm+nm) = \mathcal O(nkm),
$$
a cubic algorithm, dominated by the matrix-matrix multiplication.

On the other hand, if we use `compose_trivial`, we end up with
$$
   \mathcal O(seq(mult(AB),x)) = \mathcal O(A(Bx)) = \mathcal O(nk + km),
$$
two matrix-vector multiplications. For small `n`, `k` or `m` that's not a huge difference, but if you start to use your type-safe matrices and vectors for numerical simulation, we end up in trouble.

Also, matrix-matrix multiplication can create a dense matrix from two sparse ones, but that's going to far at this point.

By the way, `compose_trivial` does not need `Repeat`.

## Overall

I like the general approach. The ideas hold, but for ease of use we need a way to create matrices and vectors easily:

```
vector :: [a]   -> Maybe (Vector (n :: Nat) a)
matrix :: [[a]] -> Maybe (Matrix (outer :: Nat) (inner :: Nat) a)
```

Now add export lists and you have a nice, type safe vector/matrix multiplication library. However, I'm not sure whether `S (S (S (… (S Z) …)))` for large matrices leads to problems in GHC.

Comment: I understand it that, these points notwithstanding, you find the code useable? Did I succeed at making matrices rectangular (not ragged) by definition and making matrix multiplication work only on matrices of compatible size? Are these devices (`Vector`, `Matrix`, `apply`, `compose`, etc) consistent with each other? If you could add some positive points to your review, even very briefly, it will reassure me much.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov for ease of use, smart constructors are missing. Otherwise the functions are consistent and the library seems sane. Note that `compose` is usually not implemented like this, unless you _really_ want to multiply two matrices (which you try to avert as much as possible due to the \$\mathcal O(n^3)\$ complexity). Please note that this a "dry" review. I don't have GHC at hand at the moment, only repl.it.

Comment: There is a typo in a formula in the `compose` section. \$A\$ is defined two times.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. One last remark on ease of use: you mix examples and library functions in your code. If you just keep the library functions and add the example as additional codeblock/module, a follow-up question might get more traction.